# MySQL database changing data table paths or location?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, location, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench for Windows, is there a way to change the path of where MySQL data is stored? For instance, I would like to store some data in C: drive and I would like to store other data in another drive (E:) or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data is supposed to be stored under a single "datadir" in MySQL, but you can get creative with symbolic links so the data for a given database can live elsewhere.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-symbolic-links.html

Comment: Thank you, this seems simple enough.